# Error when started Spring-boot, I think it's some missing dependency

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

> INFO 9346 --- [           main] b.c.checkin.checkin.CheckinApplication

> : Starting CheckinApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on
>   MacBook-Air-de-Thomaz.local with PID 9346
>   (/Users/thomaz/Documents/Unitri/6Periodo/GestaoDaInovacao/checkin-api/target/checkin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   started by thomaz in
>   /Users/thomaz/Documents/Unitri/6Periodo/GestaoDaInovacao/checkin-api)
>   2017-09-02 15:02:57.996  INFO 9346 --- [           main]
>   b.c.checkin.checkin.CheckinApplication   : No active profile set,
>   falling back to default profiles: default 2017-09-02 15:02:58.146 
>   INFO 9346 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@41906a77:
>   startup date [Sat Sep 02 15:02:58 BRT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   2017-09-02 15:02:58.284  INFO 9346 --- [pool-1-thread-1]
>   org.hibernate.validator.util.Version     : Hibernate Validator
>   4.1.0.Final 2017-09-02 15:02:58.299  INFO 9346 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.h.v.e.r.DefaultTraversableResolver     : Instantiated an instance of
>   org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
>   2017-09-02 15:02:59.748  WARN 9346 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to process import candidates for configuration class
>   [br.com.checkin.checkin.CheckinApplication]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration
>   due to
>   org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ServletRegistrationBean not
>   found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class.
>   This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework
>   package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by
>   mistake) 2017-09-02 15:02:59.755  INFO 9346 --- [           main]
>   utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report enable debug logging (start with --debug)
>
> 2017-09-02 15:02:59.772 ERROR 9346 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to process import candidates for configuration class
>   [br.com.checkin.checkin.CheckinApplication]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration
>   due to
>   org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ServletRegistrationBean not
>   found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class.
>   This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework
>   package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by
>   mistake)  at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:616)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:548)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]   at
>   br.com.checkin.checkin.CheckinApplication.main(CheckinApplication.java:11)
>   [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>   [checkin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>   [checkin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>   [checkin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   [checkin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletConfiguration
>   due to
>   org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ServletRegistrationBean not
>   found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class.
>   This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework
>   package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by
>   mistake)  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:55)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:217)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:349)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:264)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:606)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]     ... 23 common
>   frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ServletRegistrationBean     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DefaultDispatcherServletCondition.checkServletRegistrations(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.java:166)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DefaultDispatcherServletCondition.getMatchOutcome(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.java:135)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]    ... 29
>   common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
>   ~[checkin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>     ... 32 common frames omitted

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.checkin</groupId>
    <artifactId>checkin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>checkin</name>
    <description>checkin project for college's event.</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I do not know what to do. Thanks for answer me. I'm sorry for English, I'm from Brazil.

Comment: I would recommend use https://start.spring.io/ to get a basic structure of spring boot application with all the necessary dependencies ready to use.

Comment: I'm using! This project too.

Comment: But thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you are mixing different versions of spring-boot libraries and also Spring:

- Use the same version 1.5.6.RELEASE for spring-boot-starter, spring-boot-autoconfigure, and spring-boot-maven-plugin
- I don't work with Spring boot, but I would assume that it comes with its own Spring version, so try removing the dependency on org.springframework:spring-context altogether.
- Run `mvn dependency:tree` to make sure all the versions of Spring and Spring Boot libraries are consistent

Answer (score 0):

You can check out like this, for example, this is my pom.xml hope that might help you out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.booksotre</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookstore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Bookstore</name>
    <description>frontend part</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```